# How to prove that sequence $a_n = (−1)^n+n$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have learned how to do most of the proofs that something converges, but I have no idea how to prove that something does not. If possible, I would appreciate a proof using ε-N definition; rather than just a proof by counter-example (although I know it is sufficient).

Answer (score 1):

It's not even a Cauchy sequence, because terms of even index differ by at least $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $l\in\mathbb R$ and $\varepsilon=1$. If $n>l+2$, then $(-1)^n+n=n\pm1>l+1$. Therefore,$$\bigl\lvert(-1)^n+n-l\bigr\rvert\geqslant\varepsilon.$$This  proves that no real number is limit of that sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$(-1)^n+n \ge n-1$$

For any natural number $N$ let $m\ge N+1$

Then if n>m, we have $$a_n= (-1)^n+n\ge n-1>m-1\ge N$$

Thus the sequence diverges to $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \ge 4$;

Assume $a_n=(-1)^n+n$ converges to $L \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then $a_n$ is bounded: There is a $M>0$

s.t. $0 \lt a_n <M$,  $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We have $0< n-2 < a_n <M$;

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0$ s.t.

$M +2<n_0$;

Then $M<n_0-2 <a_{n_0}$, a contradiction .